# How to handle IllegalAccessException when calling a public method

Tags: java

In reflection, there're such cases where you know the method you invoke is a public method, for example the constructor you get from `getConstructor` or `getMethod`. However, the compiler is still complain about `IllegalAccessException` when you try to invoke these methods. This is somehow contradictory, but understandable since the return type is still a `Method`. I'm just wondering what's the best practice to handle such cases? An dummy try catch can work but looks weird.

Comment: Can you provide the example code where you're getting this unexpected IllegalAccessException?

Comment: A "dummy" try-catch is required.  There's no other way, unless you plan to throw the exception, but that would be weirder.

Comment: @Jason The OP is saying that the compiler is complaining that he doesn't catch a checked exception.  The only solution is of course to add a try-catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that the *compiler* can tell whether that the method / constructor / field / whatever you code is accessing `public` or not.

For example, suppose that I write and compile the following

```
 public class Mystery {
     public static int field;
 }
```

Then I write some reflective Java code to access `Mystery.field`, and a *hypothetical* Java compiler can figure out that field is `public` and that no exception handling is needed for the checked exceptions.

Now suppose that I **modify** the `Mystery` class to make `field` a `private` member.  Then recompile it ... without recompiling the reflective code.  Now my reflective code is going to get a **checked** exception that it is not coded to handle.

---

In summary, the reflection APIs *may* throw an exception, and the Java compiler (literally) CANNOT determine if that is possible or not.  Therefore, your code *must*<sup>1</sup> deal with that possibility ... somehow.

---

> I'm just wondering what's the best practice to handle such cases? An dummy try catch can work but looks weird.

1. [There are no Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).
2. The best answer will depends on the context.
3. It is rarely a good idea to *squash* exceptions that you are not expecting.  (I assume that is what you mean by a "dummy catch".)  If your expectation is incorrect, you usually **need to know about it**.
4. Wrapping and rethrowing the exception *may be* the correct thing to do, but there is no single "best" exception to throw.  (And I personally would **never** use `RuntimeException` for this.)

---

<sup>1 - If you *really* don't like this, the solution is "simple".  Avoid using reflection in cases where the APIs you are accessing reflectively can be used without reflection ... or could be, if you redesigned them.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Rethrowing the exception is the correct thing to do, i.e.

```
try {
  Method m = ...
  m.invoke(...);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Otherwise, if the method you 'know' is public changes so that it isn't, you might never find out (if your catch clause just ignored the exception).

Answer (score 1):

> This is somehow contradictory

You can pass the name of **any** method to `getMethod`. The compiler has no way of knowing that you are requesting a public method. Hence `getMethod` declares that it ***may*** throw `IllegalAccessException`. Since that is a checked exception, your code must handle it. Presumably, if you request a public method, then the exception should not be thrown. Since it is unexpected that `IllegalAccessException` will be thrown for a public method then it is something that your code may not be able to recover from. In such cases, I usually wrap the `IllegalAccessException` in an unchecked exception, for example `RuntimeException` and throw the unchecked exception.